# Populating a NotMapped Property in a C# Model Using Values from the model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model

I'm trying to populate a read-only property in a c# model.  The idea is as follows:

```
public class UserProfile : BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string UserType {
        get
        {
            return UserManager.GetRoles(Id).First();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get the Roles that this user is in based on the value of the Id property when the model is being rendered.  Is there a method like "onCreating" that I can use to get the values that Entity framework has mapped to the properties and then use those value to populate the UserType value?  If there is a better way to do this open to ideas.  Thanks so much!

EDIT: This works!  Just had a user that wasn't in a role which is why it failed.  Hope this helps someone struggling with the same concept.

Comment: Just to clarify, when I try this code Id is always null.

Comment: Nevermind, after some debugging it turns out that this indeed works.  I was returning an IEnumerable list and some of the users weren't in roles and that's why this failed.  Awesome that this works!